# PendingIntent.getBroadcast() always returns null with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a `PendingIntent` using `PendindIntent.getBroadcast()` but it always returns null despite the docs cleary stating:

> @return Returns an existing or new PendingIntent matching the given
>   parameters.  May return null only if {@link #FLAG_NO_CREATE} has been supplied.

I'm not using FLAG_NO_CREATE so it should never return null.

```
private fun createAlertPendingIntent(
  context: Context,
  notification: Notification,
  intentId: Int) : PendingIntent {
    val notificationIntent = Intent(context, NotificationPublisher::class.java)
    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEY_NOTIFICATION, notification)

    val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        intentId,
        notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    return pi  // IS NULL
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that NotificationPublisher is a valid BroadcastReceiver that is correctly defined in your manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` can return null without any warnings or errors if something isn't right with intent you pass into it.

In my case, the notificationIntent had a `Notification` in it where the drawable used in `.setLargeIcon(drawable)` wasn't sized correctly or avalaible for all of the screen densities. Adding it to the mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc folders solved it for me.